# Is it possible to switch off The AMD ATI Radeon HD 7670M on the HP Envy 6?

Tags: ati, hp, radeon

I want to buy this laptop, but I have had issues with AMD Radeon in my previous laptop, and I want to be sure I can switch it off and use the internal intel HD4000

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but according to the research I have done (as I have the same issue), the way the GPU was designed means it cannot be turned off. The only time it is 'off' is when the GPU determines that it is not needed e.g Your web browsing and not playing games,

Comment: And could it be possible to tell when is not needed?